# How close do two wavelengths of light need to be to produce a metamer?

Tags: visible-light, geometric-optics

Suppose I have two wavelengths of light ($r_1$, $r_2$) coming from a source. These rays are then reflected specularly on a surface. What is the minimum distance required for the two wave trains of light to be considered a metamer, or perceived as one color by the eye? What would be their apparent color if $r_1$ is **590nm** and $r_2$ is **490nm**? $d_r$ is the distance between the rays and $d_e$ is the distance between the ey and the surface.

[image]

Are the two waves trains ever superpositioned into a composite wave train?

Comment: "Reflected spectacularly"? Let me guess; you were auto-corrected? :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Ah yes. It doesn't recognize "specularly"